# sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB) and (protractor.Key.RETURN) is thorwing an error

Tags: protractor

I am using keyboard keys to fill forms and using the Tab and Enter keys it throwing me an error while running in the script.

```
Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'BBUNTY', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212-release'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
UnsupportedOperationError: sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'BBUNTY', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212-release'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Below is the code I have used in the script

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
page.getUsercountrycodeinput().click().then( function(){
   page.getUsercountrycodeinput().element(by.className('ng-input'))
    .element(by.cssContainingText('ng-dropdown-panel ng-select-top', '+91'));
   browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.RETURN).perform();
});
```

it is a dropdown input field I am searching for text and then selecting the value '+91' form the dropdown field.

Chrome Version is 90.0.4430.212

webdriver version is chromedriver_90.0.4430.212.

Comment: why don't you click on it as would user do?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling w3c in your config file under capabilities.

```js
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
     w3c: false
  }
}
```

More details here - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5285

Comment: I used this config but now in my script it throwing me an error that is the same  element is not found for which the keyboard inputs are given